# How to stop propagation of mouseout event in a list?

Tags: javascript, dom-events, html-lists, mouseout, stoppropagation

When I attach a `mouseout` event to a `UL` element, event do propagate to `LI` children despite I add `stopPropagation()`? What's wrong with my code?

http://jsfiddle.net/ubugnu/D7jwq/270/

HTML code:

```
<ul id="myul">
    <li>Outer
        <ul>
            <li>Inner
                <ul>
                    <li>Inner Inner</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
<span id="count">0</span>
```

JS code:

```
document.getElementById('myul').addEventListener('mouseout', function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    document.getElementById('count').innerHTML = parseInt(document.getElementById('count').innerHTML) + 1;
}, false);
```

CSS code:

```
li { padding: 20px; border: solid 1px #ddd; }
```

Comment: Propagation happens **upwards**. You can't stop it from being run on children because they will have already processed. What is it you are trying to accomplish with this?

Comment: I want to fire a function when the mouse leaves the list

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this case, use 'mouseleave' instead of 'mouseout'. Quoting the doc:

> The [**mouseleave event**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/mouseleave) is fired when a pointing device (usually a mouse)
>   is moved off the element that has the listener attached.
>
> The [**mouseout event**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/mouseout) is fired when a pointing device (usually a mouse)
>   is moved off the element that has the listener attached **or off one of
>   its children**.

Note that `mouseleave` support has been added to Blink (Chrome/Opera 15) quite [recently](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=236215), that's why it's not available in Chrome 29 (but is already there in dev Chrome).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I tried mouseleave but it didn't work, and it seems that it doesn't work in your fiddle!

Comment: Oops! It workd on Firefox but not on Google chrome! I tried it on Google chrome that it why I missed this.
I wonder why it doesn't work on Chrome!

Comment: Okey! I've Chrome 29, is mouseleave not available for this version

Answer (score 0):

Although `mouseleave` as @raina77ow said is the correct way to do this, if you are looking for wider browser compatibility, adding this code should work:

```
var ds=document.getElementById('myul').getElementsByTagName('*');
for(var l=0;l<ds.length;l++){
    ds[l].addEventListener('mouseout',function(e){e.stopPropagation()},true);
}
```

it is untested

Comment: This does exactly what I want to avoid :)

Comment: this example fires the event each time the mouse leaves a LI, I want the event to be fired only when the mouse leave the whole UL

Comment: Sorry if the code was unclear, but this does exactly what you want. It registers an event handler on all of the children of the outer element, and that handler stops the propgation from continuing from the child (the inner lists) to the parent (the containing `ul`). Therefore, this has the desired effect. Hopefully. I haven't tested it yet

Comment: I tested it http://jsfiddle.net/ubugnu/D7jwq/273/, you see, the counter increments when we pass merely from a LI to another LI, what I want is this counter to increment when we leave the whole UL